# Do purely functional languages really guarantee immutability?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, purely-functional

In a purely functional language, couldn't one still define an "assignment" operator, say, "<-", such that the command, say, "i <- 3", instead of directly assigning the immutable variable i, would create a copy of the entire current call stack, except replacing i with 3 in the new call stack, and executing the new call stack from that point onward?  Given that no data actually changed, wouldn't that still be considered "purely functional" by definition?  Of course the compiler would simply make the optimization to simply assign 3 to i, in which case what's the difference between imperative and purely functional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell doesn't readily give you ways to introspect or "execute" call stacks, so I wouldn't worry too much about that particular bizarre scheme. However in general it *is* true that one can subvert the type system using unsafe "functions" such as `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a`. The idea is to make it difficult, not impossible, to violate purity.

Indeed, in many situations, such as when making Haskell bindings for a C library, these mechanisms are quite necessary... by using them you are removing the burden of proof of purity from the compiler and taking it upon yourself.

There is a proposal to actually guarantee safety by outlawing such subversions of the type system; I'm not too familiar with it, but you can read about it [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell).

Comment: Hmm, actually I just realized that not only doesn't Haskell give you a way to execute call stacks, but I'm thinking any pure language *couldn't* -- the call stack is constantly changing, so if there was a function GetCallStack, then that would depend on state, which I *think* would be a violation of purity.  My little workaround implicitly calls this GetCallStack, so it looks like my argument is incorrect.  Unless of course there was a state monad keeping track of the call stack for each function call, but in that case I'm basically just writing an interpreter anyway.

Comment: @Dax: That's right, for a hypothetical `getCallStack :: Stack` to be of any use, it would have to yield a different `Stack` depending on where you were in your program, which obviously violates referential transparency.

Answer (score 5):

Purely functional languages, such as Haskell, have ways of modelling imperative languages, and they are not shy about admitting it either. :)

See http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html, in particular 7.5:

> So, in the end, has Haskell simply
>   re-invented the imperative wheel?
>
> In some sense, yes. The I/O monad
>   constitutes a small imperative
>   sub-language inside Haskell, and thus
>   the I/O component of a program may
>   appear similar to ordinary imperative
>   code. But there is one important
>   difference: There is no special
>   semantics that the user needs to deal
>   with. In particular, equational
>   reasoning in Haskell is not
>   compromised. The imperative feel of
>   the monadic code in a program does not
>   detract from the functional aspect of
>   Haskell. An experienced functional
>   programmer should be able to minimize
>   the imperative component of the
>   program, only using the I/O monad for
>   a minimal amount of top-level
>   sequencing. The monad cleanly
>   separates the functional and
>   imperative program components. In
>   contrast, imperative languages with
>   functional subsets do not generally
>   have any well-defined barrier between
>   the purely functional and imperative
>   worlds.

So the value of functional languages is not that they make state mutation impossible, but that they provide a way to allow you to keep the purely functional parts of your program separate from the state-mutating parts.

Of course, you can ignore this and write your entire program in the imperative style, but then you won't be taking advantage of the facilities of the language, so why use it?

**Update**

Your idea is not as flawed as you assume. Firstly, if someone familiar only with imperative languages wanted to loop through a range of integers, they might wonder how this could be achieved without a way to increment a counter.

But of course instead you just write a function that acts as the body of the loop, and then make it call itself. Each invocation of the function corresponds to an "iteration step". And in the scope of each invocation the parameter has a different value, acting like an incrementing variable. Finally, the runtime can note that the recursive call appears at the end of the invocation, and so it can reuse the top of the function-call stack instead of growing it ([tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). Even this simple pattern has almost all of the flavour of your idea - including the compiler/runtime quietly stepping in and actually making mutation occur (overwriting the top of the stack). Not only is it logically equivalent to a loop with a mutating counter, but in fact it makes the CPU and memory do the same thing physically.

You mention a `GetStack` that would return the current stack as a data structure. That would indeed be a violation of functional purity, given that it would necessarily return something different each time it was called (with no arguments). But how about a function `CallWithStack`, to which you pass a function of your own, and it calls back to your function and passes it the current stack *as a parameter*? That would be perfectly okay. [CallCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation) works a bit like that.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking that my scheme would work even outside of the IO monad, since it truly doesn't have any side effects. However I noticed a flaw in my argument, which I highlighted in the comment to pelotom.

Comment: @Update While I haven't seen any absolute proofs, several articles I've found while searching "callcc purity" report that CallCC negates all functional purity.  While I'm not smart enough to prove that to be the case myself, I have to say it makes sense, given that the CC, though nothing but a function pointer, is nonetheless a mutating implicit context variable passed to the function.  Like I said in the other comment, it would work if you had a special continuation state monad, but, unless I'm mistaken, that more-or-less reduces to writing your own interpreter.

Comment: @Dax: That seems true to me—but if you look at the type of Haskell's [`callCC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Cont-Class.html#v:callCC), it's `MonadCont m => ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> m a`.  The continuation monad captures the semantics of continuations, and thus allows you to work that way (as long as you stay inside it).

Answer (score 2):

Immutability is a property of the language, not of the implementation.

An operation `a <- expr` that copies data is still an imperative operation, if values that refer to the location `a` appear to have changed from the programmers point of view.

Likewise, a purely functional language implementation may overwrite and reuse variables to its heart's content, as long as each modification is invisible to the programmer. For example, the `map` function can in principle overwrite a list instead of creating a new, whenever the language implementation can deduce that the old list won't be needed anywhere.

Comment: More likely optimization: If the previous list isn't needed, it probably be stream fused.